# Send JavaScript Variables with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

can someone point me out how can I send JavaScript variables with AJAX.

JavaScript:

```
var d=new Date();
document.write(d);
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax
        ({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'save.php',
          cache: false,
          data: { document.write(d); // Just for example
},
```

Everything else works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send "variables". You can only send strings (or things which can be turned into strings). (You can store those strings in variables).

A date object (which you store in `d`) can be converted into a string, so you could send that.

The return value of `document.write()` will always be `undefined`, so it doesn't make much sense to send that.

You appear to be using jQuery. The `data` property expects a standard JavaScript object. An object consists of a bunch of key/value pairs. You need to provide a key for your value.

```
data: { date: d }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could pass the value to any parameter name you want like date parameter in this example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'save.php',
    cache: false,
    data: { date: new Date()}
});
```

Or you could just use the variable like this:

```
    var d = new Date();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'save.php',
        cache: false,
        data: { date: d}
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use JSON.stringify() to convert your objects to JSON format:

```
$.ajax
    ({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'save.php',
      cache: false,
      data: JSON.stringify(d)
},
```

On the server side, of course, you would have to use a JSON parser to interpret the data.